# Malliavin derivative and conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, malliavin-calculus

I had a problem when I came across a proposition in Oksendal's book on Malliavin calculus. In the book, it claims

$$
D_t\mathbb{E}[F|\mathcal{F}_G] = \mathbb{E}[D_tF|\mathcal{F}_G]\chi_G(t)
$$
where G can be any Borel set in [0,T], $\chi$ is the indicator function.

However, when choosing G_1 = [0,t] and G_2 = [0,t), by the above theorem we have 
$$
D_t\mathbb{E}[F|\mathcal{F}_t] = \mathbb{E}[D_tF|\mathcal{F}_t]
$$
while 
$$
D_t\mathbb{E}[F|\mathcal{F}_{t-}] = 0
$$

Clearly the RHS are different in general, but the LHS is the same if the filtration is continuous, for now $\mathbb{E}[F|\mathcal{F}_{G_1}] = \mathbb{E}[F|\mathcal{F}_{G_2}]$ and so is the Malliavin derivative. This leads to a contradiction. Can anyone point where I had gone wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the topic but I suspect that Oksendal's statement should be read as follows: $$\forall \, \text{Borel sets $G$ in  $[0,T]$} \, \forall t \in [0,T]: \, \, D_t \mathbb{E}(F \mid \mathcal{F}_G) = \mathbb{E}(D_t F \mid \mathcal{F}_G) \chi_G,$$ i.e. $G$ is not allowed to depend on $t$. Perhaps I'm wrong, though.

Comment: Yeah, but for fixed t and G = [0,t) or [0,t] also fixed, the RHS are still different isnt it

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is that the malliavin derivative is not defined pathwise. We use the optional version of the process.